# MIT App Inventor: Different text sizes in the same button?

Tags: java, android, button, text, app-inventor

I am making a dialer (phone) app in App Inventor. I wanted to put the ABC after the number
(**1** abc), so that people could dial stuff like 1-800-FLOWERS. I would like to know how to make the abc font size smaller in the same button?

Comment: use the Font class for creating a custom Font object and then you can set the font of the text in the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **App Inventor** you can't change the font size in the same button.text property.
 Alternatively you could use an image with your text and put it as button.image.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Html String to a text view

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=\"32\">1</font><font size=\"20\">abc</font>"));
```

You can refer to [this](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/how-display-html-android) for details